# An Error occurred while handling another error: exception &#039;yii\web\HeadersAlreadySentException&#039

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, yii2

Установил `Yii2` и `OpenServer`. Настройки: `Apache 2.2 PHP 5.4`.

Я не понимаю, что это значит:

> An Error occurred while handling another error: exception '
>   yii\web\HeadersAlreadySentException' 
>   with message &039;
>   Headers already sent in C:\OpenServer\domains\yii\controllers\MyController.php on line 34.' 
>   in C:\OpenServer\domains\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Response.php:366 Stack trace: 0 C:\OpenServer\domains\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Response.php(339): yii\web\Response->
>   sendHeaders() 1 C:\OpenServer\domains\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\ErrorHandler.php(135): yii\web\Response->send() 2 C:\OpenServer\domains\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\ErrorHandler.php(111): yii\web\ErrorHandler->
>   renderException(Object(yii\web\HeadersAlreadySentException)) 3 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler->
>   handleException(Object(yii\web\HeadersAlreadySentException)) 4 {main} Previous exception: exception '
>   yii\web\HeadersAlreadySentException' with message 'Headers already sent in C:\OpenServer\domains\yii\controllers\MyController.php on line 34.' 
>   in C:\OpenServer\domains\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Response.php:366 Stack trace: 0 C:\OpenServer\domains\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Response.php(339): yii\web\Response->
>   sendHeaders() 1 C:\OpenServer\domains\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(392): yii\web\Response->
>   send() 2 C:\OpenServer\domains\yii\web\index.php(12): yii\base\Application->
>   run() 3 {main}

Ошибка появляется при отправке ajax, вот он:

```
$js = JS $('btn').on('click', function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?r=my/test',
    data: {
      test: 'GET-123'
    },
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(res) {
      console.log(res);
    },
    error: function() {
      alert('Error!');
    }
  });
});
JS;
$this - > registerJs($js);
```

Так принимаю:

```
public
function actionTest($id = '777') {
  $this - > layout = 'b';
  if (\Yii::$app - > request - > isAjax) {
    print_r($_GET);
    return 'test';
  }
  return "Controller - My; Action - Test";
}
```

Как исправить и что это такое? Откуда и почему ошибка появляется?

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка Headers already sent говорит о том, что заголовки были уже отправлены и не получится их отправить снова. Такое случается, когда вебмастер хочет из контроллера (!!!) отобразить какие-то данные. Разве на лекциях не говорили, что контроллер не для этого? Разве не говорили, что данные отображает вьюшка?

Если же есть совершенная необходимость отправить данные клиенту из контроллера, тогда надо завершить выполнение скриптов приложения после отправки данных, без отрисовки вьюшки.

В данном конкретном примере надо либо `print_r( $_GET);` убрать, либо после этой строки добавить `exit();`

Также, настоятельно рекомендую забыть про `$_POST $_GET`, если уж начали работать с фреймворками. Привыкаем к использованию `Yii::$app->request->post() Yii::$app->request->get()`